# When I drive my car through a puddle the power steering goes out

Tags: toyota, power-steering

1996 Toyota Camry.  I can't drive in the rain because when I do the power steering goes out.  Any ideas of what might be the problem?  No mechanic has been able to tell me what is going on.

Answer (score 6):

There's a chance that the belt may be slipping when you hit the puddle...and as a result you may be losing feedback.

How long are you *without* power steering?

Comment: only a few seconds.  If the belt is slipping what required to fix it?

Comment: There should be some form of tensioner to adjust the belt - Although at that age the belt may well be starting to perish if it hasn't been replaced, so it may well be worth replacing. A mechanic ought to be able to sport that though...

Comment: If you get your oil changed at a quicky-lube type place, they will often remove the protective plastic panel beneath the engine and discard it. This leaves the accessory bets and the rest of the engine bay exposed to the elements, causing premature wear. These panels also aid engine cooling and aerodynamics.